# Saving dataframe as another value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having some issue with copying a dataframe. Basically, I want to replicate a dataframe with another variable but with the columns being numerical instead of categorical. Below I have function that returns dataframe mean_df when I print it out I see that the rows are categorical. I then create a new dataframe (mean_df_num) which is equal to mean_df. Then I convert the rows to index values (for mean_df_num) instead of the categorical letters. However, when I print my mean_df after I see that it has also changed indices to be numerical. Why does this happen and is there a way around this?

```
mean_df = mean_funct(train_df_cat)
print(mean_df)
mean_df_num = mean_df
mean_df_num.index = range(len(mean_df_num)) #Convert df to numerical indices 
print(mean_df)
```

Output:

```
        m00      mu02       mu11
a   1.00162  0.357137  -0.245608
c  0.766659  0.354217   0.244405
e  0.929145  0.422447  0.0602329
m   1.61799   2.85194   -1.80078
n   1.03976  0.700674    -1.0011
o   0.97873  0.754065   0.172753
r  0.623244   0.11065    1.52705
s  0.789545  0.177259  -0.154744
x    1.0039  0.404982   -1.51634
z  0.919228    0.3578    0.42973 

        m00      mu02       mu11
0   1.00162  0.357137  -0.245608
1  0.766659  0.354217   0.244405
2  0.929145  0.422447  0.0602329
3   1.61799   2.85194   -1.80078
4   1.03976  0.700674    -1.0011
5   0.97873  0.754065   0.172753
6  0.623244   0.11065    1.52705
7  0.789545  0.177259  -0.154744
8    1.0039  0.404982   -1.51634
9  0.919228    0.3578    0.42973
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas dataframe is essentially a pointer. That meas when you do `mean_df_num=mean_df`, then `mean_df_num` and `mean_df` point to the same object. You change one, you change the other. The way around this is `.copy()`, i.e. `mean_df_num=mean_df.copy()`.

Actually, for your purpose, it's better just do `mean_df_num=mean_df.reset_index(drop=True)`. It does both at the same time: copy the data and set index as range index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What if I want to reset the columns as well? I don't see a reset_columns option....

Comment: That's just `mean_df.to_numpy()` to get the 2D arrays. Or `pd.DataFrame(mean_df.to_numpy())` if you really want a dataframe with range index and columns.